# What do " be down to" & "take things slow" mean in the last sentence of the following paragraph?

Tags: word-meaning

I have a miniature Australian shepherd who is my world and my baby, her name is Whiskee. Most of the time when I am at home we are outside running around or going for walks. I love to workout and stay in shape. I am currently going back to school to obtain my second bachelors in Nurse in hopes for one day to become a Nurse Practitioner. I am a very strong independent woman who also needs to her alone time. I admire love and cherish every moment of my life with the special people in it. I will do anything for my family for family is a very important aspect in my life. **I am looking for someone who is down to have fun, watch football together, and is just wanting to take things slow** .

What does it mean to say " taking things slow" ? What does it mean " be down to something" ?

Answer (score 2):

"Taking things slow" means to build up a relationship, or get to know somebody rather well before anything serious begins to occur (usually a sexual relationship, physical contact, moving in, meeting the family etc.)

> Person 1: I was wondering if you'd like to go out with me?
>
> Person 2: I just got out of a bad relationship. I'll only go out with you if we take things really slow.

"Down to [something]" means you're willing to do that something. It's slang. Down to have fun, means you're willing to just have some fun.

> Person 1: Are you down for seeing a movie tonight?
>
> Person 2: Oh, I'm so down for that!